# How to inactive Active Directory users, 1 month after their FIRST LOGIN, instead of defining a solid expiration date

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, user-management

We want to give access to some Active Directory users, so they can remotely have access to our server and download from a special folder of the server.

The licenses we give to users, are time base. There should be 1 month, 2 month, ..., 1 year, ... licenses.

**CURRENT SITUATION** (WHAT I DON'T WANT):

When users are created and added to the OS, a solid expiration date is given.

---

**WHAT I WANT:**

Users' expiration date should be calculated automatically after the first login. The user might not need his account right when purchases the license.

**In other words:**

When a license of the user we create is purchased at **Jan 1st**, he should use the license until **Feb 1st**. No matter whether he really logs in or not. He cannot come **Feb 5th** and begin using his license because that has expired then.

**What I want is that when he comes at *Feb 5th* and begins using, the license update until *March 5th*.**

---

- Working environment is Windows Server 2012.
- By the word '**user**', I mean **Active Directory Users**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a scheduled script or powershell which enumerates through users in active directory. Look for users with no expiry date set but who have a last logon date. Then set the expiry date to what you want it to be. As long as you run it at least daily you should be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much. Good idea. I accept your answer until a better answer is given `:)`

Comment: There's no native feature to do what you want, so doing something like this is probably the only way to do it.